# XML namespace issue with xjb binding file

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I have the **following xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
          targetNamespace="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          version="2.1">
    <bindings xs:schemaLocation="Inbound.wsdl#wsdl:types" node="/schema">
        <bindings node="//complexType[@name='TradeIdWithRef']">
            <bindings node=".//attribute[@name='_value']">
                <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//complexType[@name='Bank']">
            <bindings node=".//attribute[@name='_value']">
                <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//complexType[@name='Bid']">
            <bindings node=".//attribute[@name='_value']">
                <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//complexType[@name='addMarketExRequest']">
            <bindings node=".//attribute[@name='_value']">
                <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//complexType[@name='Offer']">
            <bindings node=".//attribute[@name='_value']">
                <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//complexType[@name='Price']">
            <bindings node=".//attribute[@name='_value']">
                <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//complexType[@name='Delta']">
            <bindings node=".//attribute[@name='_value']">
                <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

However I always get the following error upon xml validation:

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'bindings'. [5]
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What does the schema look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `schemaLocation` attribute must contain the **namespace of your schema** and the **path to the schema definition file**, [separated by whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856489/701303).

Also, I'm not positive it's an error, but I don't know why you would declare `schemaLocation` on a child node instead of the root.